# How can I ask question for a non-existing tag?

Tags: support, tags

I have few questions about [flowdock](https://www.flowdock.com/), since I don't have [enough reputation](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) to create the tags.

In this case how can I ask the question for the non-existing tag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have created [flowdock](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/flowdock) tag.

Generally speaking, one could ask about a new web app using some generic tags such as [chat](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chat) or [email](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/email) (depending on what the app does); someone will retag.

Comment: Thanks for adding the tag.